# How to properly set mbsync and gpg binaries path with mu4e?

Tags: init-file, mu4e, gpg, exec-path

I'm trying to sync my emails from emacs using mu4e but I get the following error message:

> Process mu4e-test exited abnormally with code 127
>
> /bin/bash: mbsync: command not found

If I set `mbsync` with its full path in my `init.el` file:

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "/usr/local/bin/mbsync -a")
```

Then I get the following error:

> sh: gpg: command not found
>
> Skipping account, PassCmd produced no output

I also tried setting the gpg path with: `(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/local/bin/gpg")` and appending the global path with `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin/")))` but none worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: For `mu4e-get-mail-command`: don't you need to also specify the mbsync config file, usually saved in `.emacs.d`? E.g., `(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "mbsync -c ~/.emacs.d/.mbsyncrc yourchannel")`, or something like that.

Comment: no, it is reading correctly from ~/.mbsyncrc

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that gpg in "PassCmd" in .mbsyncrc needs to be specified with a full path.